# jQuery Datepicker is not being executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have the following in my main php file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
</script>
```

The input box that contains the input box is being written by innerHTML.

For example, this is how the input box is being written.

echo $api->get_add_number(); calls PHP code. There is a select box that will call the following:

```
function fetch_select(val)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'fetch_data.php',
        data: {
            get_option:val
        },
        success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response;
        }
    });
}
```

From there the input box will be written and returned as innerHTML.

The issue is when I try and click the input box:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker"/>
```

I get no date pick popup. Is this because it is in innerHTML and can't be reached by javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing to do with innerHTML, the problem here is timing. All jquery plugins are built when you call its function.

So you just need to call it after include your new html

```
success: function (response) {
            document.getElementById("new_select").innerHTML=response;
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
         }
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks! I'll need to spend some time on jQuery and learning some of the more behind the scenes on how stuff works.